# Access to the path ----- is denied - vb.net

Tags: .net, ssl, windows-server-2008

I have a website which usually creates and stores all the invoices on the server, but yesterday i added SSL to the website www.accessorix.com, from then when we are trying to create invoices we are getting an error saying

Access to the path "--------------" is denied.

I found this
"You should make a class called SecurePage which inherits from your main page class (probably System.Web.UI.Page)" from [here](http://www.webfusion.co.uk/support/answers/securing-ssl-access-to-your-website-102/)

We hosting website on virtual servers in windows server 2008 R2, application using asp.net/vb.net

Any help will be highly appreciated ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it ages ago but just thought to answer it for future visitors of this post.

Basically the application uses the path as http://www.site.com as i added the SSL layer i changed the path to https://www.site.com and it worked fine.